# OrientDB - REST API - You have reached maximum pool size for given partition

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I used Apache JMeter to call OrientDB REST API to test workload of server.

I have tested with 50 concurrent user and see that ~ 30%-45% request was failed with response message as below

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": 400,
      "reason": "Bad request",
      "content": "Error on parsing parameters from request body\u000d\u000a\u0009DB name=\"data_dev\"\u000aYou have reached maximum pool size for given partition"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have checked and found no error occur on Server.

I have tried to change

`script.pool.maxSize` to `200`, `db.pool.max` to `200`

But this issue still occurred

Any suggestion?

**UPDATED**
This issue already reported [on Github at here](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6841)

Thanks.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: @OleksandrGubchenko I use version 2.2.12

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase the maximum number of instances in the pool of script engines:

`script.pool.maxSize`

Ref: [OrientDB documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Configuration.html#scriptpoolmaxsize).

Comment: Default value of `script.pool.maxSize` is 20. As I said above, I had changed this value to 200. But no change!

Comment: Changed this value to 2000. The issue still occur.

Comment: Can you also check the `client.channel.maxPool`? http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Configuration.html#clientchannelmaxpool Also run `CONFIG` comand from console and check if values were updated.

Comment: `client.channel.maxPool` is 100. I changed it to 2000. But the issue still occur.